# How can I make Volley Response String readable?

Tags: java, android, rest, android-studio, android-volley

When I want to make an API request to the server through Postman, the response is correct and readable. But When I want to make the same request through Volley Android it returns response as a string, which is unreadable. Just like this -  [image]

Can anyone tell me where is the problem and how can I fix it?
Here is Code - `public void fetch_value() {

```
    StringRequest getRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //Response value
                    
                    
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                 
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("pasword", pasword);
           
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            Map<String, String> responseHeaders = response.headers;
            String json = null;
            String newStr=null;
            try {
                json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return Response.success(json, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError 
        {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
            params.put("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
            params.put("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.82 Safari/537.36");
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
            params.put("Origin", "http://abc.in");
            params.put("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin");
            params.put("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors");
            params.put("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "empty");
            params.put("Referer", "http://abc.in/xyz.action");
            params.put("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            params.put("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en;q=0.9");
            params.put("Connection", "keep-alive");
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        }

        @Override
        protected String getParamsEncoding() {
            return "utf-8";
        }
    };`
```

Comment: post your android volley code

Comment: Check my edit code.

Comment: you can use Volley JsonObjectRequest to get the response as a json object. is that what you want?

Comment: No. If I use JsonObjectRequest there is arising Parse error as value like the image I given Can not be converted to JsonObject.